# Jquery .click event doesn't fire what could be the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following jquery script in a Razor view with layout set to the null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $('#shareapp').click(function () {
            check_if_fb_is_defined();
        });
        window.fbactivity_id = '@Model.Id';
        window.fbactivity_name = 'your-hollywood-movie';
        window.wallpost_name = 'How would be your hollywood movie poster look like ?';
        window.wallpost_picture = '@ViewBag.ImageURL';
        window.wallpost_description = 'How would be your hollywood movie poster look like?';
        window.wallpost_link = '@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority,Url.Action("campaign_result", "facebook", new { @resultid = Model.Id, @imgURL = ViewBag.ImageURL  })))';
        window.wallpost_caption = 'Ozhay';
        window.tags = 'Naser';
        function check_if_fb_is_defined() {
            if (typeof (FB) === 'undefined') {
                fbsharer();
            } else {
                PostShare('@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority,Url.Action("campaign_result", "facebook", new { @resultid = Model.Id, @imgURL = ViewBag.ImageURL})))';
            }
        }
        function PostShare(mylink) {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'share',
                href: mylink,
                hashtag: '#Ozhay',
            }, function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error_message) {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Wallpost', 'Facebook', window.fbactivity_name, window.fbactivity_id);

                } else {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Wallpost', 'No', window.fbactivity_name, window.fbactivity_id);
                }
            });
        }

        //if FB is undefined
        function fbsharer() {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Dialog', 'Facebook', window.fbactivity_name, window.fbactivity_id);
            window.fb_sharer_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(window.wallpost_link);
            window.popupWindow = window.open(window.fb_sharer_url, 'facebooksharer', 'height=567,width=572');

            var popupTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                if (typeof window.popupWindow !== 'undefined') {

                    if (window.popupWindow.closed !== false) {
                        window.clearInterval(popupTimer);
                    }
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    })
</script>
```

I have added Jquery script file to the view but for whatever reason When I click on a link that has `shareapp` id nothing happens. This is a bit strange to me where sometimes before it worked. your thoughts about this?

Comment: Your script has errors. Always first check in the console, to see what is reported there. You have a missing closing brace and closing parenthesis.

Comment: That is not the issue It is because I did remove some of scripts from my code for brevity. Do you think that causes jquery not to fire? Duh

Comment: Did you check the console? There is still a syntax error ....

Comment: Yes gives a syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More] help

Comment: So, did you correct it?

Comment: yes but still no luck @trincot

Comment: No more errors in console? Did you define the function `ga`? This really is basic debugging. Just debug the code with `console.log(...)` calls at different places, ... etc, etc.

Comment: No more error but I get this warning @trincot `Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead`

Comment: You can ignore that for now. What if you click? Anything in console?

Comment: @trincot my bad, Thanks a lot that solved the issue but I didn't clicked the link :P Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. FB is undefined - where do you declare FB?

   ```
       function check_if_fb_is_defined() {
           if (typeof (FB) === 'undefined') {
               fbsharer();
           } else {
   ```
2. Syntax error - Need ')' before ';' at end of PostShare.

   ```
               PostShare('@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority,Url.Action("campaign_result", "facebook", new { @resultid = Model.Id, @imgURL = ViewBag.ImageURL})))';
           }
       }
   ```

   })

Comment: fixed it but still no luck firing that event handler

Comment: What is the console log you get back? perhaps put debugger into your function to walkthrough the procedure?

Comment: Why do you have `Postshare(`....`)` all written out, when you can just use the variable reference as an argument `Postshare(window.wallpost_link);`?